# Wix How to schedule the XmlConfig run after ConfigureIIs?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

We need use the xmlconfig to update the applicationHost.config under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. And the action should run after ConfigureIIs.

But by default the XmlConfig will run before ConfigureIIs.

Could you please give some clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under my team member's help.
Add the following ExecuteSequence will resolve the issue.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SchedXmlConfig" After="ConfigureIIs"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```